# XMLHTTP request not parsing XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest, xhtml

Im trying to consume some xml and serve it in xhtml based on [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_responsexml)
but i get:

**Error:**

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
...f5r.xhtml
Line Number 16, Column 37:
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
------------------------------------^
```

**The f5r.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<folio name="f5r" wordCount="56" width="1067" height="1500">
  <word index="0" x="131" y="202" width="70" height="49">hello</word>
  <word index="1" x="212" y="198" width="62" height="65">world</word>
</folio>
```

**The f5r.xhtml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../../vms.css"?>
<script src="../../public/javascripts/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            myFunction(this);
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "f5r.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }

      function myFunction(xml) {
        var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        txt = "";
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("folio");
        for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
          txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("folio").innerHTML = txt;
      }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
  <img class="foliophoto" id="f5r_lg"/>
<div class="folios">
<p class="folio">

  <!-- <xml src="f5r.xml"></xml> -->

</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem may be with JQuery not loading locally but im not sure nor am i sure why JQ isnt working locally but ive had that problem in the past before.

update: case sensitivity was not the problem. "folio" also doesnt work.

Comment: x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue will be a whitespace string. Did you mean `getElementsByTagName("word")` rather than `getElementsByTagName("folio")`?

Comment: Your HTML namespace is wrong. It should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, not `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1`

Comment: thanks. it seems the 1 is extraneous in the ns too. getting rid of that and leaving the `&&` untouched in the CDATA has got the JS working now at least. still not getting the xml imported though.

Comment: the XMLDoc gotten from the xml response is exactly the whole folio xml that i want to append to the div element, but appendChild doesnt allow adding a HTMLCollection so i guess it needs to be done as above retrieving and adding the text. but not sure why its erroring now.

Comment: Got the text added to the <p> innerHTML. Turns out the added break `</br>` was causing it not to add and to error because it also needed to be escaped: `&#xD;`. Wasnt shown in w3.example. Still unsure why undefined was added to text as i was now getting elements by `<word>` tagname so it shouldnt have been getting the `<folio>` & its null/undefined element but inspecting the response & indeed it was!  but it was the breaks that caused it not to display. note that i only needed to escape the `&&` in the request only with the CDATA tag. so this questions && error is resolvedby @kjhuges answer.

Comment: and so before adding to the <p> innerHTML i can just get the substring to removed the `undefined` text. `txt=txt.substring(9);`

Comment: moving the loadXMLDoc() call from the buttons onclick event to the body onload event (as in the initial question), causes it to not display again, which i suspect is another issue of synchronicity.

Comment: it appears from logging to console that the loadXMLDoc() is not even being called on the body's onload or onLoad event.

Comment: get around onload not firing by triggering it manually on document load   `document.onload = loadXMLDoc();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within parsed character data, `&` is expected to begin an entity reference such as `&amp;`.

The standard solution is to wrap your JavaScript in a `CDATA` section so that `&&` isn't interpreted as markup, and use JavaScript comments so that the `CDATA` delimiters are ignored by JavaScript:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
     JavaScript code here
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: got rid of the error, but just interprets the script as data & browser prints script to the screen. `function loadXMLDoc() { var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){ myFunction(this); } }; xmlhttp.open("GET", "f5r.xml", true); xmlhttp.send(); } function myFunction(xml) { var x, i, xmlDoc, txt; xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; txt = ""; x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FOLIO"); for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) { txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>"; } document.getElementById("folio").innerHTML = txt; } `

Comment: ie, dom loads `<script>cdata-section</script>`

Comment: sounds right. but still just prints all of the JS with the // to the screen, doesnt get the data into the <p>. btw when i was trying to use jquery, or even just console.log("hello") it was just printing to the screen and not to console. something may be wrong with my JS...

Comment: after escaping the ampersands and encasing in the cdata tags, safari gives me an error that may be more helpful than firefox. it seems to be related to (this)[https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361245/safari-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-error-1-on-local-html-files#368178] and it may be because my files are on an external device. `(kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)" (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork:1)`

Comment: actually it only did that once, its showing the same now, the xml html tree but with no data in the paragraph where i want it to be injected. with not sure why that error came up but i can try to move it onto my main drive.

Comment: still not getting xml data injected into dom when i tried moving onto local HD and also tried serving via MAMP server.

Comment: @jsky - `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FOLIO")` should be `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("folio")` - remember that XML is case-sensitive. Don't know why the script is being displayed, but it could be something in your CSS.

Comment: @Alohci thanks i did try that already, wasnt the problem, but your correct i just didnt update it on this page yet.

Comment: and its not just a css display issue, as the xml is not in the dom tree when i inspect. however i guess its possible that some javascript i inherited is mucking with it.